# Django Erro SECRET_KEY

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando rodar um codigo e quando eu tento dar um 'MIGRATE' eu tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
(myenv) ➜  django-file-manager git:(main) ✗ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/.pyenv/versions/3.9.14/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/djangoFileManager/settings.py", line 25, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/decouple.py", line 206, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/decouple.py", line 90, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jonatascarvalho/django-file-manager/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/decouple.py", line 75, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: SECRET_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

Ja verifiquei o meu arquivo Settings.py e esta assim:

```
Django settings for djangoFileManager project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config
from dj_database_url import parse as dburl

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Rodei o echo $SECRET_KEY e ele retorna em branco. Alguem ja passou por isso?

Ja verifiquei o meu arquivo Settings.py e esta assim:

```
Django settings for djangoFileManager project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config
from dj_database_url import parse as dburl

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Rodei o echo $SECRET_KEY e ele retorna em branco.

Comment: "*Rodei o echo $SECRET_KEY e ele retorna em branco*", então, não deveria estar em branco, né?

Comment: Você está usando `SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')`, neste caso ou crie o SECRET_KEY como variável de ambiente (`export SECRET_KEY=SUA_SECRET_KEY_AQUI`) ou crie um arquivo `.env` no mesmo diretório do settings.py contendo a variável.

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado @PauloMarques